# Reading and writing data in Firebase

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to increment energy values of each user in my Android app.

Here is the scheme of my database:

```
"Users" : {
    "NRPdi5gzbsWoHSfovOtIO8XgFjZ2" : {
      "Character" : {
        energyCurrent : 0,
        energyMax : 100,
        energyObtain : 20,
        and other char values..
      }
    }
}
```

I read, do some calculations and write data with this code, but nothing changes in my Firebase database. This code is on Google App Engine. No exceptions sent, just nothing happens.

```
final FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("Users");

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        int energyCurrent;
                        int energyMax;
                        int energyObtain;
                        try {
                            energyCurrent = (int) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyCurrent").getValue();
                            energyMax = (int) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyMax").getValue();
                            energyObtain = (int) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyObtain").getValue();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        float finalEnergy = energyCurrent + (energyMax * (energyObtain/100));
                        if (finalEnergy > energyMax){
                            DatabaseReference reference = childSnap.getRef().child("Character").child("energyCurrent");
                            reference.setValue(energyMax, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                throw databaseError.toException();
                            }
                        });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DatabaseReference reference = childSnap.getRef().child("Character").child("energyCurrent");
                            reference.setValue((int)finalEnergy, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                throw databaseError.toException();
                            }
                        });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you using the Admin SDK?  Did you create a service account and use it to [authenticate your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#admin-sdk-authentication)?

Comment: You're ignoring the problems that `onCanclled()` might report. To catch them `throw databaseError.toException()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201612140118182865968

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no exceptions thrown with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement throws an exception for every iteration of your loop:

```
energyCurrent = (int) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyCurrent").getValue();
```

`getValue()` on a numeric string returns a `Long`, which cannot be unboxed to `int`, and instead throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

The `continue` statement in the catch-block transfers control to the end of the loop's body, skipping the code containing the calls to `setValue()`.

You can use a double cast for the three statements:

```
int energyCurrent = (int)(long) dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue();
```

Or make your variables `long`s and use a single `(long)` cast:

```
long energyCurrent;
long energyMax;
long energyObtain;
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot be cast integer in long variable, if u insist to use that, cast :

```
try {
     energyCurrent = (int)(long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyCurrent").getValue();
     energyMax = (int)(long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyMax").getValue();
     energyObtain = (int)(long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyObtain").getValue();
 }
```

and you should remove :

```
throw databaseError.toException();
```

on the OnComplete Database